# jquery - getting the next 6 results

Tags: jquery, list

I have the following list

```
<li>option 1</li>
<li>option 2</li>
<li>option 3</li>
<li>option 4</li>
<li>option 5</li>
<li>option 6</li>
<li class="hidden">option 7</li>
<li class="hidden">option 8</li>
<li class="hidden">option 9</li>
<li class="hidden">option 10</li>
<li class="hidden">option 11</li>
<li class="hidden">option 12</li>
<li class="hidden">option 13</li>

<a href="">My Link</a>
```

I would like a function that when the link is clicked, the first six list items with the class "hidden" will remove that class and display on screen.

Any help is appreciated.

James

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector:

```
$("li.hidden:lt(6)").removeClass("hidden").show();
```

Or, alternatively, the [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method, which is better if the number of items to match can vary:

```
var itemCount = 6;
$("li.hidden").slice(0, itemCount).removeClass("hidden").show();
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Is there a way I can also tell when there are no more hidden list items?

Comment: Yes, `$("li.hidden").length` will be `0` if there are no `<li>` elements with the `hidden` class, and `$("li:hidden").length` will be `0` if there are no `<li>` elements that are actually hidden.

Answer (score 1):

use JQuery [lt](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) to filter the results -

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("li.hidden").lt(6).removeClass("hidden").show();
});
```